# Changing Live wallpaper based on user selected interval

Tags: android, intervals, android-handler, wallpaper, live-wallpaper

> Im new to andriod development. I have developed an app to set live
>   wallpaper and wallpaper will change on intervals selected by user from
>   dropdown. I have used WallpaperService to implement this. Handler with
>   runnable is used to set the wallpaper and
>   handler.postDelayed(runnable, WALLPAPER_DURATION); is used to trigger
>   to change the wallpaper for selected interval. Problem is wallpaper
>   rotates for the first selected interval, when user changes to another
>   interval say from 5mins to 10mins, wallpaper should change for every
>   10mins, but my code is still changing it for 5mins.Im able to get the
>   user changed interval in the service but im not able to kill the
>   runnable in handler.postDelayed. I have used
>   handler.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);
>   handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);  but dint help. I want to
>   kill or update the runnable with new delay time(interval).

```
Runnable drawRunner = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("TIMER SCHEDULED "+WALLPAPER_DURATION);
                drawFrame();
                incrementCounter();
            }

        };
        public MyWallpaperEngine() {
            System.out.println("MyWallpaperEngine ");
            mImagesArray = new int[] {R.drawable.one,R.drawable.two,R.drawable.three,
                    R.drawable.four,R.drawable.five,R.drawable.six,
                    R.drawable.seven,R.drawable.eight,R.drawable.nine,
                    R.drawable.ten};
            handler.post(drawRunner);
        }

        private void incrementCounter() {
            mImagesArrayIndex++;

            if (mImagesArrayIndex >= mImagesArray.length) {
                mImagesArrayIndex = 0;
            }
        }

        private void drawFrame() {
            System.out.println("inside draw frame");
            SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();
            System.out.println("holder Object " + holder);
            Canvas canvas = null;

            try {
                canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
                System.out.println("Canvas Object " + canvas);
                if (canvas != null) {
                    System.out.println("inside draw image");
                    drawImage(canvas);
                }
            } finally {
                if (canvas != null) {
                    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }

            handler.postDelayed(drawRunner, WALLPAPER_DURATION);
            if(clearHandler){
                    System.out.println("inside remove callbacks");
                   handler.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);
                  handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
                  clearHandler=false;
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onSurfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            System.out.println("onSurfaceDestroyed is called");
            super.onSurfaceDestroyed(holder);
            //handler.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);
            //handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        }

        private void drawImage(Canvas canvas)
        {
            Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    mImagesArray[mImagesArrayIndex]);
            Bitmap b=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), true);
            canvas.drawBitmap(b, 0,0, null);
        }

        public void onDestroy(){
            super.onDestroy();
        //    handler.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);
          //  handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this base code.

```
private final Handler handler = new Handler();
        private final Runnable drawRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                iteration();
                draw();
            }
        };
        protected void iteration(){
            handler.removeCallbacks( drawRunnable );
            if( visible ){
                handler.postDelayed( drawRunnable, 1000);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can I know what's the difference between my code and Ur suggestion. U have called removecallbacks and postdelay in a method and I have put the same in draw method itself. Moreover I want wallpaper to get updated even the phone is in sleep mode. If I put postdelay inside visible it will be updated only when awake on home screen. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @Override
        public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean isVisible){
            if( isVisible ){
                handler.post( drawRunnable );
            }else{
                handler.removeCallbacks( drawRunnable );
            }
        }

Comment: Onvisibitychanged will trigger only when awake right? I don't want this. I want wallpaper to set when on sleep mode to so I don't override this method

Comment: I'm in very need and very important at earliest. Please help to solve this issue